# Order missing in admin end

Tags: magento-1.8

A customer has placed an order successfully and transaction was successful because customer is having transaction ID but there is no sign of order in admin-end.

Can anyone please help me to debug the issue?

I can notice an entry for that order in 'sales_flat_quote' table but there is no entry for that order in 'sales_flat_order' table

Comment: Even there is an entry in sales_flat_quote_payment table for the payment through credit card but no entry at all in sale_* tables

Comment: While looking into the issue, I found the entry for that order in admin->reports->shopping carts->abandoned cart.
Can anyone tell me what does that actually mean and why?